# Issue with scope, or passing by reference, or something else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building an expressJS app and want to make it super easy to add endpoints. So I have an Endpoint class that handles a bunch of stuff, including providing basic CRUD functions to the Express Router

But, when I instantiate multiple Endpoints, and call the functions associated with their routers, it's like they are always executing the functions defined in whatever Endpoint I instantiated first.

The setup here isn't using express, but illustrates the same problem.

I haven't tried much, accept boiling the problem down to the minimally sufficient code required to demonstrate the issue.

You can see the code below, or check out https://repl.it/@SethGreen1/WhoppingJuniorTerabyte

Here is the `index.js` file that kicks everything off:

```
const Router = require('./router.js');
const Endpoint = require('./endpoint.js');

const AppleEndpoint = new Endpoint("Apple");

const OrangeEndpoint = new Endpoint("Orange");

const AppleRouter = AppleEndpoint.getRouter();

const OrangeRouter = OrangeEndpoint.getRouter();

AppleRouter.executeRoute("get");

OrangeRouter.executeRoute("get");
```

And, router.js:

```
class Router {

    constructor() {
      this.routes = [];
    }

    addRoute(name, func){
      this.routes[name] = func;
    }

    executeRoute(name){
      this.routes[name]();
    }
}

module.exports = new Router();
```

And finally, endpoint.js

```
const Router = require('./router.js');

class Endpoint {

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getRouter() {

      Router.addRoute("get", () => {
        console.log(this.name);
      });
      return Router;
    }

    getName() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
}

module.exports = Endpoint;
```

I'm expecting this code to print:

```
Apple
Orange
```

Instead, it is printing:

```
Orange
Orange
```

Comment: you basically created a singleton by using `module.exports = new Router()` instead of `module.exports = Router`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating your Router class inside it's own file, hence creating a *singleton*.

> A singleton ensures a class only has one instance, and provide a global point of access to it.

To avoid that, you need to instantiate it in the Endpoint `constructor`. See below

`Enpoint.js`:

```
const Router = require('./router.js')

class Endpoint {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.router = new Router()
  }

  getRouter () {
    this.router.addRoute('get', () => {
      console.log(this.name)
    })
    return this.router
  }

  getName () {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

module.exports = Endpoint
```

and `Router.js`:

```
class Router {
  constructor () {
    this.routes = []
  }

  addRoute (name, func) {
    this.routes[name] = func
  }

  executeRoute (name) {
    this.routes[name]()
  }
}

module.exports = Router
```